# Persistence unit exception

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

i've this problem with my Enterprise Java Bean.
Log file:
[stack trace](http://pastebin.com/r2vWn7jp)

I don't know how to resolve it! This is my Entity class:

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


    /**
     *
     * @author gfucc
     */
    @Entity
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Students"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByMatr", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.matricola = :matricola"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByCognome", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.cognome = :cognome")
    })
    public class Student 
    {
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private String matricola;

        @NotNull
        @Column(length = 100)
        private String nome;

        @NotNull
        @Column(length = 100)
        private String cognome;

        @NotNull
        @Column(length = 100)
        private String corsoLaurea;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 0, max = 30)
        private int numEsamiSostenuti;

        public Student()
        {

        }

        public Student(String nome, String cognome, String corsoLaurea, int numEsamiSostenuti) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.cognome = cognome;
            this.corsoLaurea = corsoLaurea;
            this.numEsamiSostenuti = numEsamiSostenuti;
        }

        public String getMatricola() {
            return matricola;
        }

        public void setMatricola(String matricola) {
            this.matricola = matricola;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public String getCognome() {
            return cognome;
        }

        public void setCognome(String cognome) {
            this.cognome = cognome;
        }

        public String getCorsoLaurea() {
            return corsoLaurea;
        }

        public void setCorsoLaurea(String corsoLaurea) {
            this.corsoLaurea = corsoLaurea;
        }

        public int getNumEsamiSostenuti() {
            return numEsamiSostenuti;
        }

        public void setNumEsamiSostenuti(int numEsamiSostenuti) {
            this.numEsamiSostenuti = numEsamiSostenuti;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" + 
                    "matricola=" + matricola + 
                    ", nome=" + nome + 
                    ", cognome=" + cognome + 
                    ", corsoLaurea=" + corsoLaurea + 
                    ", numEsamiSostenuti=" + numEsamiSostenuti + '}';
        } 
    }
```

This is my EJB:

```
package ejbs;

import entities.Student;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import qualifiers.Loggable;

/**
 *
 * @author gfucc
 */
@Stateless
@Loggable
public class StudentEJB implements StudentEJBRemote 
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "StudentEJBPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Student createStudent(Student student)
    {
        em.persist(student);
        return this.getStudentByMatricola(student.getMatricola());

    }

    @Override
    public Student removeStudent(Student student) 
    {
        Student toReturn = this.getStudentByMatricola(student.getMatricola());
        if(toReturn != null)
        {
            em.remove(student);
            return toReturn;
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public Student updateStudent(Student student) 
    {
        return em.merge(student);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> getStudentList() 
    {
        TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createNamedQuery("Student.findAll", Student.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentByMatricola(String matricola) 
    {
        TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createNamedQuery("Student.findByMatr", Student.class);
        query.setParameter(1, matricola);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentByCognome(String cognome) 
    {
        TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createNamedQuery("Student.findByCognome", Student.class);
        query.setParameter(1, cognome);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }


}
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="StudentEJBPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <class>entities.Student</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Now in these images you can see my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVVAq.png)

What is the problem? I've all. The database i connected, i used a default database "sample"... The problem is on the persistence unit because without it i can build and then deploy without problem! Please help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using Java 6? Also, you have not specified the JPA provider in the persistence.xml file.

Comment: The error points to classloading the javax/persistence/PersistenceException class, so something is wrong with what you are including in your application.  What jars are you packaging and using when you get the exception?  My guess is your runtime is missing a JPA jar with above mentioned class.